# an exercise about finite extension field and root of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots, extension-field

Suppose $K|F$ is a field extension of degree $n$ and $f(X)\in F[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $m\ge 2$ and $(m,n)=1$. Prove that $f(X)$ has no root in $K$.

thanks

Comment: Counterexample: $K=\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$, $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $f(X)=(X^2+1)(X+1)$, so $\deg f=3$. $f$ splits completely over $K$. You may want $f$ to be irreducible.

Comment: u're right!what can be said if we assume $f$ to be irreducible?

Comment: If it is irreducible, what do you know about $[F(\alpha) : F]$ where $\alpha$ is any zero of $f$ in some field extension of $F$?

Comment: it is the degree of minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ on $F$,it is not more than $m$

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ has a root $\alpha \in K$, then this gives us $[F(\alpha):F]=m$. But this divides $[K:F]=n$, a contradiction.

(The assumption that $n,m$ are coprime is too strong; we just need that $m$ does not divide $n$.)