# a question about field extensions and tower formula

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

if $K|F$ is a field extension & $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are the elements of $K$ which are algebraic on $F$ , we know that $[F(a_1,a_2,...,a_n):F]=<\Pi_{i=1}^n[F(a_i):F]$,it can be proved by induction on $n$.

is it also true that $ (\Pi_{i=1}^n[F(a_i):F])$ is divisible by $[F(a_1,a_2,...,a_n):F]$?
is any condition necessary for this?

any proof or counter example is welcomed.

thank u very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the case $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $a_1=\root3\of2$, $a_2=\omega\root3\of2$, where $\omega=(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$ is a primitive third root of unity.

Comment: in this example we have:$[F(a_1):F]=3$ and $[F(a_2):F]=3$ and $[F(a_1,a_2):F]=6$.so this is a counter example. true?

Comment: Correct, @user115608 :-)

Comment: can u pls see this?nobody has answered.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959512/an-exercise-about-finite-extension-field-and-root-of-a-polynomial